# QT5 requires OpenGL desktop on i.Mx6 (buildroot)

Tags: qt5, embedded-linux, buildroot, imx6, bsp

I'm using 'imx6-sabresd_qt5_defconfig' on i.Mx6 (buildroot) and qt app is QT box demo.
When I run app, it show this error:

```
error: This example requires Qt to be configured with -opengl desktop
```

How to fix this? Do I need to add something in menucofig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your platform provides an OpenGL ES (OpenGl for embedded systems) implementation. This example requires a full OpenGL implementation. It is just not a suitable for your platform.

Comment: The box demo is for full OpenGL not OpenGL ES. I try cube demo it runs successfully. Thanks